# Build a NAND gate using multiple NAND gates

Tags: logic-gates, atomic-code-golf

A question that had popped up in my head once - how many NAND gates would it take to build a larger, "meta-NAND" gate?

Your task is to build a black-box circuit that takes two input wires `A` and `B` and returns one output wire that satisfies `A NAND B`, subject to the following restrictions:

- You must use at least two `NAND` gates in this construction (and no gates other than `NAND`).
- You may not have null configurations of gates - that is, systems of gates that are equivalent to a gateless wire. (For example, two `NOT` gates in series are a null configuration.)
- You cannot have any stray wires (discarded values or constants).

Fewest gates wins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## 4 gates

(A NAND B) AND-using-NAND (A NAND B)

```
A---NAND        _
 \ /    \      / \
  X      NAND-<   NAND-->
 / \    /      \_/
B---NAND
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Three gates.  Compute (((A nand A) nand B) nand B).  Unlike the four-gate solution above in which three of the four gates compute A nand B, two of them simultaneously, and substituting one of the simultaneous outputs for the other would yield two consecutive inverters, the three-gate solution uses the three gates to compute different functions: "not A", "A or not B", and "A nand B".  Only the last gate computes the desired function.

Answer (score 7):

## 3 gates

```
   /-----------\
A-<             \
   \-----\       \
          \       NAND--
           NAND--/
B-<NAND---/
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/24992/34718), (but with A and B switched)